How has this integral been written as a line integral?
I am right now self-learning Green's functions for partial differential equations and I am stuck at the very last step of deriving the adjoint operator.
To begin, the PDE of interest is $\textbf L u = A u_{xx} = \phi$ where $u_{xx} = \partial ^2u/\partial x^2 $. The book I am following,  introduces the adjoint operator,$\textbf L^*$, using integration over a region, $R$, as
$$
\iint_{R}^{} v  \ \textbf Lu \ d\sigma = boundary\_terms + \iint_{R}^{} u  \ \textbf L^{*}v \ d\sigma
$$,
where $d\sigma$ is an elemental area in the XY plane.
Now, if I apply this multiple integral on the PDE, I get the result as
$$
\iint_{R}^{} v  \ \textbf Lu \ d\sigma = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \left . \left [ v Au_x - (vA)_xu) \right ] \right|_{x_1(y)}^{x_2(y)} dy + \iint_{R}^{} (vA)_{xx}u \ d\sigma
$$
,where $x_1(y)$ and $x_2(y)$ are the definition of curves in terms of $y$.
This multiple integral is evaluated over a region $R$ which has a boundary $\Gamma$. The unit normal to this boundary is $\widehat{n}$. Now, the author simplified the first integral in the RHS of previous result of multiple integration as
$$
\iint_{R}^{} v  \ \textbf Lu \ d\sigma = \int_{\Gamma}^{}\left [ v Au_x - (vA)_xu) \right ]\overrightarrow{i}\cdot \widehat{n} \ ds
+ \iint_{R}^{} (vA)_{xx}u \ d\sigma
$$
, where $ds = ds \ cos(\theta) = \overrightarrow{i}\cdot \widehat{n} \ ds$ is an elemental arc length.
I am not able to understand how the first integral has been written as line integral. I understand that the $X$ component of the unit normal to the boundary has been used but, in this context I don't understand the overall simplification/conversion procedure to line integral.
Can someone point out to what I am missing ?
EDIT - I am aware of the fact that divergence theorem can also be used here but I want to use the approach of repeated integration by parts.

Which author of which text?

"Applications of Green's functions in science and engineering", Greenberg(1971), Dover Publications.
